# Ionic how to back not in tabs. Ionic History

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, url-routing

I have an example of ionic. Use the tabs layout. When I open a view (this view does not belong to tab), how do I use $ionicHistory.goBack()?

I know tabs hava stack , product-detail is a root stack,not in tabs stack. now how can does give product-detail on tabs current stack. Or have other methods goBack ?

Thank you

[app home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TEwG.jpg)
[pagedetail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLvz1.jpg)

#config#

```
.state('tab', {
   url: '/tab',
   abstract: true,
   templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
 })
// Each tab has its own nav history stack:
.state('tab.dash', {
  url: '/dash',
   views: {
     'tab-dash': {
     templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
     controller: 'DashCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.category', {
  url: '/category',
  views: {
    'tab-category': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-category.html',
      controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
    }
  }
})
. state('tab.cart',{
  url:'/cart',
  views:{
    'tab-cart':{
      templateUrl:'templates/tab-cart.html',
      controller:'CartCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.account', {
  url: '/account',
    views: {
     'tab-account': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
      controller: 'AccountCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('product-detail',{
    url:'/products/:product_id',
    templateUrl:'templates/product-detail.html',
    controller:'ProductDetailCtrl'
})
```

Comment: You are redirecting to `product-details` via `products` page. Right?

Comment: hi.thank you. yes . it's right. sorry. I can't express in English.    I hava three tab. then have  tab1 stack,tab2 stack,tab3 stack.  and I hava other page ,not in tabs . so the other page have a root stack.  but , I want other page belong to the current tab stack. Because $ionicHistory.goBack() can use.   **like this  tab1-> productdetails .  productdetails can back tab1. tab2->products->productdetails  .productdetails can back products. products can back tab2.**

Comment: you can do that if you redirect to those other pages via the current tab page: for eg in href of a link you can put "/products/23" where 23 is your product id and this opened link would have back page as the products page.